# How could I put an ad on the left hand side of a blog post - and have the text wrap around it

Tags: wordpress

So I have been trying a bunch of things and got nowhere.

I have a blog and basically what I want to do is to add an 300x600 on the left hand side of the content automaticly. In the Single.php, I seem to only have the option of adding an ad unit before of after the content - and not during. (A typical scenario would be a 600 word post and 640x400 featured image at top.)

I want the the 300x600 banner to be in the middle of the post, with 150px being inside and outside of the 960px content area. A image describes this better.

[image: Example]

The above is a ruff picture, but I hope you get the idea. I want the text to "wrap" around the image.

I was thinking something like this:

```
$content = get_the_content();
// if the post has > 800 characters, show top ad
if ( mb_strlen($content) > 400 ) {
?>
<?php if ( function_exists('show_ad_1') && show_ad_1() ) echo '<div id="ad-abovepost">'      .show_ad_1(). '</div>'; ?>
```

}

I believe that will trigger an ad after a certain amount of characters (not what I am after, but its a start), but I cant control where the ad goes inside the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

The left aligning the image is easy to do. Ensuring it shows up in the middle of the article can be a bit more tricky.

Perhaps it would be good to try to find the first paragraph break after the first 300 or 400 characters and then you can insert the image right there.

inserting this text should get you in the right direction

```
[caption align="alignleft" width="300"]<a href="link-goes-here"><img  src="ad-image-goes-here.png" alt="" width="300" height="600" /></a> You should click this ad[/caption]
```